# Make UserControl keep square shape

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, user-controls

I'm working on **Windows Phone 8 C#/XAML project** and I've run into a problem, where I can't think of a solution.

**The problem**

I'd like my usercontrol to be square at all times (but not fixed size square).

**For example**

I have a grid, where the width and height of columns is automatically calculated (*width="*"* and *height="*"* in all *column* and *row definitions*) and I have one of these controls in each of the grid's cells and I'd like them to keep square shape.

**Questions**

- **How to achieve this? Are there multiple ways?**
- **I've read somewhere about rewriting SizeChanged event, but I can't think of a code that will work, if possible can someone hint me with an algorithm and/or code?**

Comment: Maybe binding usercontrols height to width will do the job.

Comment: You mean bind every usercontrol's width to height when using? That seems a bit like scratching your right shoulder with your left foot.

Comment: Hmm the problem can be when you can't exacly tell which size (height or width) is grater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}"`

or vice versa to Width & ActualHeight would generally be the way to go, even if it's "scratching your right shoulder with your left foot." You could set it as a Style Template to the `TargetType` to have it inherited and not reiterate everywhere.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The way I saw the proposal Romasz made seemed that way. This one with a bit more of explanation seems to clear the issue for me. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got your remedy. Make sure to mark questions correct if answered for others who may have the same issue. Cheers!